# Scala Upper Type Bounds for Primitive Types

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I want to write a generic class that overload operators. But I want to limit the types to Int, Long and Double. Is it possible to create an upper type bound for primitive types?

Here is what I have done for Int. I need to make this class generic and it should only accept Int, Long and Double. If this is not the right approach I hope someone can give an alternative solution for the problem.

```
class MyClass(value: Int) {
  def +(operand: Int): MyClass = { 
    return new MyClass(value+operand);
  }

  def -(operand: Int): MyClass = {
    return new MyClass(value-operand);
  }

  def *(operand: Int): MyClass = {
    return new MyClass(value*operand);
  }

  def /(operand: Int): MyClass = {
    return new MyClass(value/operand);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Type Class Pattern](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html). I would require an implicit `MyClassOperators[T]` to be in scope, and implement it only for the desired `Int`, `Long` and `Double`.

Define the trait implementing the operations:

```
object MyClassImplicits {
  trait MyClassOperators[T <: AnyVal] {
    def +(firstOperand: T, secondOperand: T): MyClass[T]

    def -(firstOperand: T, secondOperand: T): MyClass[T]

    def *(firstOperand: T, secondOperand: T): MyClass[T]

    def /(firstOperand: T, secondOperand: T): MyClass[T]
  }
```

Now lets provide a concrete implementation for `Int`:

```
implicit object MyClassIntOperators extends MyClassOperators[Int] {
  override def +(firstOperand: Int, secondOperand: Int): MyClass[Int] = new MyClass[Int](firstOperand + secondOperand)

  override def -(firstOperand: Int, secondOperand: Int): MyClass[Int] = new MyClass[Int](firstOperand - secondOperand)

  override def *(firstOperand: Int, secondOperand: Int): MyClass[Int] = new MyClass[Int](firstOperand * secondOperand)

  override def /(firstOperand: Int, secondOperand: Int): MyClass[Int] = new MyClass[Int](firstOperand / secondOperand)
}
```

And change the definition of `MyClass` to require the implicit `MyClassOperators[T]` to be in scope:

```
class MyClass[T <: AnyVal : MyClassOperators](val value: T) {
    def doSomeAddition(otherValue: T): MyClass[T] = {
      implicitly[MyClassOperators[T]].+(value, otherValue)
    }
}
```

When we run this with an `Int` instance:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val myClassOfInt = new MyClass[Int](1)
  println(myClassOfInt.doSomeAddition(2).value)
}
```

Yields:

```
3
```

But when we try this with a `Double` instance (which isn't implemented yet):

```
[error] could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type tests.NewTest.MyClassImplicits.MyClassOperators[Double]
[error]     val myClassOfInt = new MyClass[Double](1.0)
[error]                        ^
[error] one error found
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems like a very good solution. I'll give it a go and check it and accept this answer.